# jquery beginner: change background on click

Tags: jquery, colors, click

I'm trying to change the background of an element on click based on the current color.

Here's the relevant html:

```
<div id="rect" style="height: 100px; width:300px; background: red">
</div>
```

and my jquery attempt:

```
    $("#rect").click(function() {
    if ($(this).css('background') == 'red') {
        $(this).css('background','blue');}
    else {$(this).css('background','yellow');}
    });
```

I'm always getting a yellow box; the 'true' condition never fires.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try: `if ($(this).css('background-color')`, as jquery breaks down "background" to its different properties, thus `'background` is probably returning a much longer line, or possibly nothing at all. Tho I think jQuery returns colors in RGB format and not literal strings. Red would be `rgb(255, 0, 0)`

Comment: jQuery may not even normalize colors to a specific format, so different browsers *may* return colors in different formats. It's something to be aware of.

Comment: Answer updated with test responses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **UPDATE**

I found one exception, as expected, in IE. To account for IE exception, simply use jQuery's [**.browser**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/) Method. I've added this to below example code.

Try:

```
$("#rect").click(function() {
    var red = $.browser.msie ? "red" : "rgb(255, 0, 0)";
    if ($(this).css('background-color') == red) {
        $(this).css('background','blue');}
    else {$(this).css('background','yellow');}
});
```

As I explained in my comments, jQuery breaks down each part of CSS property "background", thus you need to call the exact Property you want, in this case `background-color`. Also, jQuery returns color values as RGB style, thus red would be `rgb(255, 0, 0)`. Now this doesn't stop `.css("background"` from being useful to **SET** background, just remember, just like css, *background* will override all other background-direct properties.

Apparently someone made a jsFiddle example for me. (Thank you [Sushanth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/941272/sushanth))

### See it Here

Also @RyanKinal make a good point in his comment *"jQuery may not even normalize colors to a specific format, so different browsers may return colors in different formats. It's something to be aware of."* <strike>I've not tested</strike> ...

CSS "red" as returned via different browsers:

- Firefox 17: "rgb(255, 0, 0)"
- Chrome 24: "rgb(255, 0, 0)"
- Opera 12: "rgb(255, 0, 0)"
- Safari 5: "rgb(255, 0, 0)"
- IE 7-9: "red"

Comment: @Sushanth-- lol, you edited while i was editing. I added link to your fiddle in answer and a `Thank you`. :D

Comment: Thanks to all. Using background-color seems obvious now, but I wouldn't have considered the red/rgb issue. Good lesson for me.