# Jquery change image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a beginner in jQuery trying to change image background on click of a button I made. 
It changes when i click on the image, but i cant make it work with button. 
Thank you. I am a newbie. Sorry

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#img').on({
    click: function() {
      $(this).addClass('alternate').removeClass('cali')
    }
  });
});
```

```css
button {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 50px;
  width: 150px;
}

.img {
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.cali {
  background-image: url("http://www.hdwallpaper.nu/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/california_wallpaper_21.jpg");
}

.alternate {
  background-image: url("http://www.hdwallpaper.nu/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/california_wallpaper_15.jpg");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div href="#" class="img cali"></div>
<button id="change">Change</button>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery beginner: change background on click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13687963/jquery-beginner-change-background-on-click)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understand your requirements correctly you can try following

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#change').on(
    'click',
    function() {
      $('.img').toggleClass('alternate')
    }
  );
});
```

```css
button {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 50px;
  width: 150px;
}

.img {
  background-size: cover;
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url("http://www.hdwallpaper.nu/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/california_wallpaper_21.jpg");
}

.alternate {
  background-image: url("http://www.hdwallpaper.nu/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/california_wallpaper_15.jpg");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="img cali"></div>
<button id="change">Change</button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. :) 
I've been trying to do this for 2 days now.
how  can I position the button on top of the image? I'm sorry

Answer (score 0):

try this. your #img must be .img. base on your code

```
$(document).ready( function() {
$('.img').on({
click: function(){
$(this).addClass('alternate').removeClass('cali') }
});             
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In below code I've fixed the errors you had in your code.

Try this

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('.img').on('click', function(){
     $(this).addClass('alternate').removeClass('cali')
  });
});
```

Demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/g7y1sqfb/)

Also, [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) works, like in the @Bilal's answer. But it keeps switching.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just have a few syntax errors. You are using a class for `img` so use a dot instead of hashtag. Also your on click function needs to look like below.

Should be more like this:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('.img').on( 'click', function() {
        $(this).addClass('alternate').removeClass('cali');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to apply click event to `button` not to `div`.You can use `toggleClass` to alternate between the class

Here is the code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $(".img").toggleClass("alternate");
    });
});
```

In case of multiple buttons you can use id of the button in this case `#change`.

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#change").click(function(){
         $(".img").toggleClass("alternate");
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

- Add or remove alternate and cali class using a if statement.
- If you you want to set height of .img element to 100%, you should also set height of all it's parents to 100% too (including html, body tags)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#change').click(function () {
      if ($('.img').hasClass ("alternate")) {
        $('.img').removeClass('alternate');
        $('.img').addClass('cali');
      }
      else {
        $('.img').removeClass('cali');
        $('.img').addClass('alternate');
      }
  });
});
```

```css
html,body { height: 100% }
button {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 50px;
  width: 150px;
}

.img {
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.cali {
  background-image: url("http://www.hdwallpaper.nu/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/california_wallpaper_21.jpg");
}

.alternate {
  background-image: url("http://www.hdwallpaper.nu/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/california_wallpaper_15.jpg");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div href="#" class="img cali"></div>
<button id="change">Change</button>
```